# Choosing random number for object ID?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

I'm implementing a reference counting base class and would like to set uniqe number for each object being created which inherits that interface.

here is a code snippet from that class:

HEADER:

```
    class Object
    {
        const long long int object_id;
    public:
        Object();
        virtual ~Object();
    };
```

CPP:

```
    Object::Object() : object_id(reinterpret_cast<long long int>(&object_id))
    {
    }
```

I'm corious if that's safe approach or not, if not why not?
I didn't use rand and srand function because of 2 reasons:

1. srand AFAIK is best to use only one time in a project to make random numbers as much as possible random.
2. this approach is more precise since two objects can not share same memory location.

please advice me.

EDIT:
At which point is member object_id created? inside of constructor or outside (before initializatin list or after) hm hm?
thanks alot!

Comment: How about using a good old GUID?

Comment: Can you use the object instance pointer as the ID? It's difficult to answer this question because it depends what you need the ID for exactly; what kind of behaviors must it follow with regards to copying, serializing, lifetimes, etc

Comment: thanks, how to use GUID in C++?

Comment: How do you want to *use* the reference counting? Why can't you just use an ordinary `std::shared_ptr` to your objects?

Comment: @tenfour "object instance pointer" that means each object will have such pointer, so I'll eather use it's address as id or what. itn't tahts the same as my example? thanks. (yeah I'll implement copy constructor as well later)

Comment: @Kerrek SB why would I use std::shared_ptr each time for object creation, that's what I'm trying to make automaticaly in some way by implementing reference counting objects, thanks.

Comment: Am I missing something? I mean, why do you take the address of a member variable (which basically is the same as `this`) and then store it? Why not use `this`?

Comment: @Mr Lister object_id(reinterpret_cast<long long int>(this)) this does not work :) or how do u mean use this?

Answer (score 3):

It's not a safe approach. You haven't considered non-virtual multiple inheritance. It's rare, but legal.

```
class A : public Object {};
class B : public Object {};
class C : public A, public B {}; // Now C has *two* IDs!
```

Comment: It depends on your definition of "safe".  There are two `Object`s, so there are two IDs.

Comment: Wow, good spot. I didn't think about that :/ so what do you recommend in this situatin by chossing unique ID for object? thanks

Comment: @codekiddy Tell us what you want to use thes IDs for first. Uniquely identifying an object for the app lifetime? Or "for ever"? Basically *what are you going to do* with this ID?

Comment: @Cicada I'll store this id into std::map of another class which will handle events by choosing function pointer assigned to that object, not only that but this id will be used for other purposes as well(but most important is handlig events emited from objects which emits same events) also I'll use it to auto delete objects.

Answer (score 1):

OK this is first time I'm answering to my own question but here is what I did to make unique_id work.

```
//this is base class which only hold the id and may be inherited only by Object class
struct object_id
{
//friend class Object;
//protected:  MAKE IT PUBLIC FOR TESTING PURPOSES! FOR NOW
    int id;
    object_id()  : id(reinterpret_cast<int>(&id)) { } //id will be 100% uniqe
};

//this class inherits virtualy so the id member will be in each derived class only once!
class Object : virtual public object_id  //INHERIT PRIVATE LATER, now it's public for testing!
{ 
public: 
     Object(){}
     virtual ~Object(){}
    };
```

TEST:

```
//now let's make some diamod inheritance to se if it work:)

class a: public Object{};
class b: public Object{};
class c: public a,b{};

//now let's test it:

int main()
{
    c obj;
    c ss;
    c dd;
    cout << endl << obj.id << endl << ss.id << endl << dd.id << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

This works just fine and every object now has it's own unique ID!